# Hot to use material Scaffold with CupertinoTabBar

Tags: flutter, material-design

I want my app to have a bottom bar with tabs (just like Fultter's `CupertinoTabBar`), but use Material design for all the rest.

My attempt looks like this:

app.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:steal_map/src/map_tab.dart';

import 'list_tab.dart';
import 'map_tab.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const appTitle = 'MyApp';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // Use the green theme for Material widgets.
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return CupertinoTheme(
          data: const CupertinoThemeData(),
          child: Material(child: child),
        );
      },
      home: HomePage(),
    );

  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
        tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: MapTab.title,
              icon: MapTab.icon,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: ListTab.title,
              icon: ListTab.icon,
            ),
          ],
        ), tabBuilder: (context, index){
          switch(index)
          {
            case 0:
              return MapTab();
            case 1:
              return ListTab();
            default:
              assert(false, 'Unexpected tab');
              return const SizedBox.shrink();
          }
    });
  }

}
```

map_tab.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:steal_map/src/app.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapTab extends StatefulWidget {
  static const title = 'Map';
  static const icon = Icon(CupertinoIcons.map);

  const MapTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MapTabState();
  }
}
class _MapTabState extends State<MapTab> {

  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  static const CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 0,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 0,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(App.appTitle),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.settings,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // do something
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        label: const Text('To the lake!'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
      ),
    );

  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
  }

}
```

Result:
[image: screenshot]

I guess `Scaffold` was not meant to be used like that, but what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so is somebody had a similar problem, here is how you do it:

`Scaffold` was not meant to be created inside another `Scaffold`, and definitely not inside a `CupertinoTabScaffold`. That's why the result looks bad.

The desired result can however be easily achieved without using cupertino widgets at all.

Material `Scaffold` also has it's own bottom bar.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: {...},
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    selectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 170, 0),
    currentIndex: tabIdx,
    onTap: (index) => changeTab(index),
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.map), label: 'Map'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.list), label: 'List'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

And inside the `MapTab` class just return a `Container` instead of a `Scaffold`.